# Using firebase tools as a node module in firebase function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to call the export method from the firebase tools node module in a firebase function.

```
    await firebase_tools.auth.export(tempLocalFile);
```

But i am receiving the following error

```
FirebaseError: No currently active project.
To run this command, you need to specify a project. You have two options:
- Run this command with [1m--project <alias_or_project_id>[22m.
- Set an active project by running [1mfirebase use --add[22m, then rerun this command.
To list all the Firebase projects to which you have access, run [1mfirebase projects:list[22m.
To learn about active projects for the CLI, visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli#project_aliases
```

Is there a way to set the active project in the nodejs cloud function?

Edit

I am initialising the object like so

```
const firebase_tools = require('firebase-tools');
```

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple Firebase projects in a Cloud function or something?

Comment: Nope just the one its deployed to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly replying to your problem, but note that the `auth.export` command will not work in a Cloud Function.

As explained in the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) (See the note at the bottom):

> when used in a limited environment like Cloud Functions, not all
> firebase-tools commands will work programatically **because they require
> access to a local filesystem**.

This is the case for the `auth.export` command. An alternative is to use the `listUsers()` method of the Admin SDK, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#list_all_users).